# 18.04 GNOME stutters every second after running for a while

Tags: gnome, graphics, gnome-shell

Recently, my GNOME desktop has begun to stutter after running for a while (on the order of a day or so of uptime).  These stutters are very brief--I really only notice them during video playback or when in a smooth-scrolling app--and seem to occur whenever the system time ticks one second.

- I'm running GNOME 3.28.2 with **no** plugins.
- I'm using the nvidia 390 driver on a GTX 960.

  - Force Full Composition Pipeline had no effect.
- My audio and, curiously, the mouse pointer seem unaffected.

I really have no idea how to even diagnose this.  Any ideas?  What other info can I provide?

Answer (score 1):

To add to OP:
I have the same issue. Audio, mouse, and full-screen games run smoothly. This makes me think it must be an issue with gnome.

Video showing the issue:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_JQXGBygBbQ

Narrowing down the issue:
- Forcing to my Intel GPU doesn't resolve the issue
- Downgrading to gnome-shell==3.28.1 doesn't fix anything
- I'm running nvidia driver v390.77. Downgrading to v390.48 doesn't make a difference either
- I couldn't test using nouveau drivers

EDIT: my problem was the system monitor extension. If anyone else ends up here like me: https://github.com/elvetemedve/gnome-shell-extension-system-monitor/issues/3

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/905724)

Comment: I have the same question but want to add additional detail. I don't want to create a duplicate question. How can I do that here on AskUbuntu?

Comment: In that case it would be best to upvote the question and leave a comment instead of an answer. To leave a comment you need a reputation of 50, but that should be achieved pretty fast here.